# How can I get all items to display as columns using SQL pivot when number of items is large?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table like so:

```
SalesPerson Product SalesAmount
Bob         Pickles $100.00
Sue         Oranges $50.00
Bob         Pickles $25.00
Bob         Oranges $300.00
Sue         Oranges $500.00
```

and I wanted to get

```
SalesPerson Oranges Pickles
Bob         $300.00 $125.00
Sue         $550.00
```

I would use:

```
SELECT SalesPerson, [Oranges] AS Oranges, [Pickles] AS Pickles
FROM 
(SELECT SalesPerson, Product, SalesAmount
FROM ProductSales ) ps
PIVOT
(
SUM (SalesAmount)
FOR Product IN
( [Oranges], [Pickles])
) AS pvt
```

However this would be a bit of a pain if I had a large number of products and I wanted to get the same result. I'm guessing I could use a Select statement like so:

```
FOR Product IN(SELECT DISTINCT(Product) FROM ProductSales
```

but I would still need to define the individual column headings i.e.

```
    SELECT SalesPerson, [Oranges] AS Oranges, [Pickles] AS Pickles, [Bagels] AS Bagels, [MonsterTrucks] AS MonsterTrucks...
```

Is there a more efficient way of going about achieving this?

Comment: No doubts,you have to use dynamic sql to do so.If you are to display in front like asp.net then write simple query in proc and do the pivot part in c#, for example

Comment: Unfortunately this has to be done using pure sql

Comment: no problem,even dynamic sql is easy and fast.you can just start over with 2-3 items.

Comment: check my latest,it is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see,i do not know you exact table design.
I am just trying to give you rough idea here,And this is just main part of whole query .

```
 Declare @item varchar(500)
    Declare @Sql varchar(max)

    create   table t (SalesPerson varchar(50), Product varchar(50), SalesAmount float)
    insert into t values
    ('Bob','Pickles', 100.00)
    ,('Sue','Oranges', 50.00)
    ,('Bob','Pickles', 25.00)
    ,('Bob','Oranges', 300.00)
    ,('Sue','Oranges', 500.00)

    ;With CTE as
    (
     Select distinct product from t
    )

    select 

        @item=stuff((select ','+ '['+ product + ']' from cte for xml path('')),1,1,'')
     from CTE A
    print @item --debug

    set @sql=' SELECT SalesPerson, '+@item+'
    FROM 
    (SELECT SalesPerson, Product, SalesAmount
    FROM t ) ps
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (SalesAmount)
    FOR Product IN
    ( '+@item+')
    ) AS pvt '
    print @sql --debug
    exec (@sql)
```