# SQL Server : selecting from 2 other tables in same result

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with a little complicated query. I have to select data from 2 tables which looks like this:

Table1:

```
 ID     Prob  Cost  Visible    
-------------------------
12345    100   50    1
12346    90    333   1
```

Table2:

```
 ID     Item1    Count
-----------------------
12345    555       3
12345    666       5
12345    777       20
12345    888       2
12346    111       5
12346    222       6
12346    333       2
```

I need to make output like this:

```
 ID    Prob  Cost Itm1 Cnt1 Itm2 Cnt2 Itm3 Cnt3  Itm4 Cnt4  Visible
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12345   100   50   555  3    666  5    777  20    888  2      1
12346   90   333   111  2    222  5    333  2     0    0      1
```

So all needed I think is some simple loop with count of items from table 2 and add columns with count and item number to result. I've tried a lot of solutions but cannot find a suitable one.

Heres correct data:

well so thats this query in my case:

```
DECLARE 
@sql1   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
@sql2   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
@sql3   VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
t1.UniqueID
,t1.TargetItemNum
,t1.MixingProbability
,t1.MixingCost' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) +' THEN SourceItemNum  END), 0) AS [SourceItemNum' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10) +
'   ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) +' THEN SourceItemCount  END), 0) AS [SourceItemCount' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY TargetItemNum) AS RN
FROM ti_ItemMixingInfo
)t

SELECT @sql3 =
'   ,Visible
FROM ti_ItemMixingInfo t1
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY SourceItemNum)
FROM ti_ItemMixingElement
)t2
ON t2.UniqueID = t1.UniqueID
GROUP BY t1.UniqueID,t1.TargetItemNum, t1.MixingCost, t1.MixingProbability, t1.Visible
'

PRINT @sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3
EXEC(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

and thats the result:

```
1   7000630 10000   5230    7000780 3   1
2   7000640 10000   5230    7000780 3   1
3   7000650 10000   5038    7000780 3   1
4   7000660 10000   5038    7000780 3   1
```

first table[ti_ItemMixingInfo]:

```
UniqueID TargetItemNum MixingProbability MixingCost Visible
1      7000630          10000          5230        1
2      7000640          10000          5230        1
3      7000650          10000          5038        1
4      7000660          10000          5038        1
```

second table[ti_ItemMixingElement]:

```
UniqueID SourceItemNum SourceItemCount
1      7000780         3
1      7000800         5
1      7001350         10
1      7008410         1
1      7008420         1
2      7000780         3
2      7000800         5
2      7001420         10
2      7008410         1
2      7008430         1
3      7000780         3
3      7000800         5
3      7001360         10
3      7008380         1
3      7008390         2
4      7000780         3
4      7000800         5
4      7001380         10
4      7008380         1
4      7008410         2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i solved similar problem y'day.check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961753/how-can-i-get-all-items-to-display-as-columns-using-sql-pivot-when-number-of-ite/28962244#28962244

Comment: are all the columns integers ?

Comment: It's probably a task for the presentation level, but if you really need to solve it at the database, do a search for dynamic pivot, plenty of examples here.

Comment: Should the 2nd row be: `12346   90   333    111    5    222   6   333   2`?

Comment: Could you update your sample data with the correct one?

Comment: i have answered with correct one please check this out

Comment: @GameDev, see updated answer. Your `@sql2` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a dynamic crosstab:

```
DECLARE 
    @sql1   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
    @sql2   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
    @sql3   VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
    t1.ID
    ,t1.Prob
    ,t1.Cost' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) +' THEN Item1  END), 0) AS [Itm' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10) +
'   ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) +' THEN Count  END), 0) AS [Cnt' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Item1) AS RN
    FROM Table2
)t

SELECT @sql3 =
'   ,Visible
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Item1)
    FROM Table2
)t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Cost, t1.Prob, t1.Visible
'

PRINT @sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3
EXEC(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Prob        Cost        Itm1        Cnt1        Itm2        Cnt2        Itm3        Cnt3        Itm4        Cnt4        Visible
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------
12345       100         50          555         3           666         5           777         20          888         2           1
12346       90          333         111         5           222         6           333         2           0           0           1
```

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/880ec/1/0)

---

**EDIT**: From you update, your `@sql2` is wrong:

```
DECLARE 
    @sql1   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
    @sql2   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
    @sql3   VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
    t1.UniqueID
    ,t1.TargetItemNum
    ,t1.MixingProbability
    ,t1.MixingCost' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) +' THEN SourceItemNum END), 0) AS [Itm' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10) +
'   ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) +' THEN SourceItemCount  END), 0) AS [Cnt' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY SourceItemNum) AS RN
    FROM ti_ItemMixingElement
)t

SELECT @sql3 =
'   ,Visible
FROM ti_ItemMixingInfo t1
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY SourceItemNum )
    FROM ti_ItemMixingElement
)t2
    ON t2.UniqueID = t1.UniqueID
GROUP BY t1.UniqueID,t1.TargetItemNum, t1.MixingCost, t1.MixingProbability, t1.Visible
'

PRINT @sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3
EXEC(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

See [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3dcc/1/0)

Comment: its generally ok but its getting column count from first row and if first row have less ingreediens than rest then its bugged and not showing correctly

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide additional data?

Comment: replied check this out please

Comment: Could you add column name? It's had to understand. Also I suggest you delete that answer and post that onto your question,

Comment: but anyway columns are not in order, first is 4 then  1, then 4 then 5 and then 2

Comment: You could add an `ORDER BY RN` on `@sql2`, after the inner select (after `)t`).

Comment: just need to add one column in result before Visible its count of ingreeditens (count of used columns) which are not null so for example if its SourceItem1 SourceItemCount1 SourceItem2 SourceItemCount2 and rest are nulls i need to add Count() of SourceItem1 and SourceItem2 (2)

Comment: ahh solved by adding ,Count(RN) before Visible in sql3